# Cannot access WMS.GetMap as anonymous in geoserver

Tags: caching, geoserver, wms

I seem to be having issues with getting geoserver to use the built in geowebcache to create tiles.

I have created a folder called geotiles I added the folder in the system environment variables.
I have also added :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR</param-name>
        <param-value>C:\geotiles</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

into the web.xml that resides in geoserver/WEB-INF.

I have set project to 3857,4326 and 900913 and it is currently on 900913.

It hase created a geowebcache.xml and a tmp folder so far in my geotiles folder but thts about it.
I am pasting what my geowebcache.xml file looks like so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gwcConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://geowebcache.org/schema/1.5.0 http://geowebcache.org/schema/1.5.0/geowebcache.xsd" xmlns="http://geowebcache.org/schema/1.5.0">
  <version>1.5.0</version>
  <backendTimeout>120</backendTimeout>
  <gridSets>
    <gridSet>
      <name>CMA_EPSG:4326</name>
      <description>A default WGS84 tile matrix set where the first zoom level covers the world with two tiles on the horizonal axis and one tile over the vertical axis and each subsequent zoom level is calculated by half the resolution of its previous one.</description>
      <srs>
        <number>4326</number>
      </srs>
      <extent>
        <coords>
          <double>1830416.01738695</double>
          <double>-4142368.28270507</double>
          <double>3662526.00111207</double>
          <double>-2525543.22436482</double>
        </coords>
      </extent>
      <alignTopLeft>false</alignTopLeft>
      <resolutions>
        <double>0.703125</double>
        <double>0.3515625</double>
        <double>0.17578125</double>
        <double>0.087890625</double>
        <double>0.0439453125</double>
        <double>0.02197265625</double>
        <double>0.010986328125</double>
        <double>0.0054931640625</double>
        <double>0.00274658203125</double>
        <double>0.001373291015625</double>
        <double>6.866455078125E-4</double>
        <double>3.433227539062E-4</double>
        <double>1.716613769531E-4</double>
        <double>8.58306884766E-5</double>
        <double>4.29153442383E-5</double>
        <double>2.14576721191E-5</double>
        <double>1.07288360596E-5</double>
        <double>5.3644180298E-6</double>
        <double>2.6822090149E-6</double>
        <double>1.3411045074E-6</double>
        <double>6.705522537E-7</double>
        <double>3.352761269E-7</double>
      </resolutions>
      <metersPerUnit>111319.49079327358</metersPerUnit>
      <pixelSize>2.8E-4</pixelSize>
      <scaleNames>
        <string>EPSG:4326:0</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:1</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:2</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:3</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:4</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:5</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:6</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:7</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:8</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:9</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:10</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:11</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:12</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:13</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:14</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:15</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:16</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:17</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:18</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:19</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:20</string>
        <string>EPSG:4326:21</string>
      </scaleNames>
      <tileHeight>256</tileHeight>
      <tileWidth>256</tileWidth>
      <yCoordinateFirst>false</yCoordinateFirst>
    </gridSet>
    <gridSet>
      <name>CMA_EPSG:900913</name>
      <description>This well-known scale set has been defined to be compatible with Google Maps and Microsoft Live Map projections and zoom levels. Level 0 allows representing the whole world in a single 256x256 pixels. The next level represents the whole world in 2x2 tiles of 256x256 pixels and so on in powers of 2. Scale denominator is only accurate near the equator.</description>
      <srs>
        <number>900913</number>
      </srs>
      <extent>
        <coords>
          <double>1830416.01738695</double>
          <double>-4142368.28270507</double>
          <double>3662526.00111207</double>
          <double>-2525543.22436482</double>
        </coords>
      </extent>
      <alignTopLeft>false</alignTopLeft>
      <resolutions>
        <double>156543.03390625</double>
        <double>78271.516953125</double>
        <double>39135.7584765625</double>
        <double>19567.87923828125</double>
        <double>9783.939619140625</double>
        <double>4891.9698095703125</double>
        <double>2445.9849047851562</double>
        <double>1222.9924523925781</double>
        <double>611.4962261962891</double>
        <double>305.74811309814453</double>
        <double>152.87405654907226</double>
        <double>76.43702827453613</double>
        <double>38.218514137268066</double>
        <double>19.109257068634033</double>
        <double>9.554628534317017</double>
        <double>4.777314267158508</double>
        <double>2.388657133579254</double>
        <double>1.194328566789627</double>
        <double>0.5971642833948135</double>
        <double>0.2985821416974068</double>
        <double>0.1492910708487034</double>
        <double>0.0746455354243517</double>
      </resolutions>
      <metersPerUnit>1.0</metersPerUnit>
      <pixelSize>2.8E-4</pixelSize>
      <scaleNames>
        <string>EPSG:900913:0</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:1</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:2</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:3</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:4</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:5</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:6</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:7</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:8</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:9</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:10</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:11</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:12</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:13</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:14</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:15</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:16</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:17</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:18</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:19</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:20</string>
        <string>EPSG:900913:21</string>
      </scaleNames>
      <tileHeight>256</tileHeight>
      <tileWidth>256</tileWidth>
      <yCoordinateFirst>false</yCoordinateFirst>
    </gridSet>
    <gridSet>
      <name>CMA_EPSG:3857</name>
      <srs>
        <number>3857</number>
      </srs>
      <extent>
        <coords>
          <double>1830416.01738695</double>
          <double>-4142368.28270507</double>
          <double>3662526.00111207</double>
          <double>-2525543.22436482</double>
        </coords>
      </extent>
      <alignTopLeft>false</alignTopLeft>
      <resolutions>
        <double>156543.03390625</double>
        <double>78271.516953125</double>
        <double>39135.7584765625</double>
        <double>19567.87923828125</double>
        <double>9783.939619140625</double>
        <double>4891.9698095703125</double>
        <double>2445.9849047851562</double>
        <double>1222.9924523925781</double>
        <double>611.4962261962891</double>
        <double>305.74811309814453</double>
        <double>152.87405654907226</double>
        <double>76.43702827453613</double>
        <double>38.218514137268066</double>
        <double>19.109257068634033</double>
        <double>9.554628534317017</double>
        <double>4.777314267158508</double>
        <double>2.388657133579254</double>
        <double>1.194328566789627</double>
        <double>0.5971642833948135</double>
        <double>0.2985821416974068</double>
        <double>0.1492910708487034</double>
        <double>0.0746455354243517</double>
      </resolutions>
      <metersPerUnit>1.0</metersPerUnit>
      <pixelSize>2.8E-4</pixelSize>
      <scaleNames>
        <string>EPSG:3857_0</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_1</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_2</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_3</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_4</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_5</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_6</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_7</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_8</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_9</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_10</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_11</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_12</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_13</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_14</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_15</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_16</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_17</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_18</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_19</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_20</string>
        <string>EPSG:3857_21</string>
      </scaleNames>
      <tileHeight>256</tileHeight>
      <tileWidth>256</tileWidth>
      <yCoordinateFirst>false</yCoordinateFirst>
    </gridSet>
  </gridSets>
  <layers/>
</gwcConfiguration>
```

this is how my geserver logs looks so far.

```
2014-08-12 10:52:11,266 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished SEED task after 1.813 seconds
2014-08-12 10:52:11,266 ERROR [seed.MTSeeder] - Problem communicating with GeoServer
org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheException: Problem communicating with GeoServer
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:522)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:711)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Cannot access WMS.GetMap as anonymous
    at org.geoserver.security.OperationSecurityCallback.operationDispatched(OperationSecurityCallback.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.fireOperationDispatchedCallback(Dispatcher.java:729)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:724)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.dispatchOwsRequest(GWC.java:1162)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:572)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:517)
```

this is how my caching defaults look like:

[image]

[image]

I also get this in my geoserver logs:

```
2014-08-12 10:51:43,952 INFO [geoserver.gwc] - Saving GeoSeverTileLayer CMAInfo:tbl_drwg_zoning_outline
2014-08-12 10:51:43,952 INFO [file.FileBlobStore] - C:\geotiles\CMAInfo_tbl_drwg_zoning_outline does not exist or is not writable
2014-08-12 10:51:43,952 INFO [file.FileBlobStore] - C:\geotiles\CMAInfo_tbl_drwg_zoning_outline does not exist or is not writable
2014-08-12 10:51:43,952 INFO [file.FileBlobStore] - C:\geotiles\CMAInfo_tbl_drwg_zoning_outline does not exist or is not writable
2014-08-12 10:52:09,453 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-1 begins seeding layer : CMAInfo:Base
2014-08-12 10:52:09,485 WARN [layer.MetaTile] - ********* Native JAI is not installed, meta tile cropping may be slow ********
2014-08-12 10:52:09,547 INFO [geoserver.wms]
```

this is for all my layers that i have I get that in my logs.
I also thought it might of been my folder access but I set that users and everyone has full read write access to it but that still hasn't done anything.

If anybody could tell me if i am missing something or a step is missing or if I missed something.

Comment: Is your Geoserver set up to require authentication for WMS requests?

Comment: Where would I find if it is or not?

Comment: Check [Geoserver service security](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/service.html). I am just guessing but it may be that one of these settings is blocking GeoWebCache from making the requests it needs to. Try allowing anonymous read only access (i.e. just GET WMS requests).